# "Add unimplemented methods" feature in the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In the Eclipse IDE there is a great feature allows you to add (implement) all of the required methods of the particular class. I'm looking for this feature in the Android Studio IDE, but without success so far. Is there something similar? For me it is one of the key-features and can't live without.

**edit:**

I don't want to choose methods to implemet. I want IDE to do it for me like Eclipse were doing. For example when I clicked "Add unimplemented methods" inside any `Activity` extented class all of these `onCreate()` `onPause()` `onResume()` were generated.

Comment: Pressing `alt+enter` on the class name doesn't do that?

Comment: Intelij shortcut : ctrl+I (probably the same on Android Studio). Alt+INSERT : show you a popup with different thing to generate.

Comment: Yeah. I suggest `alt+insert` because you can do anything with it in IntelliJ IDEA :)

Comment: You can also hover the mouse over the class name, then click the red lightbulb "thingy" that appears :)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

**Of course there is.** It is called **Implement methods** or **Override Methods**. The default shortcut is **CTRL-I** and **CTRL-O**. See descrption of [Implementing Methods](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/implementing-methods-of-an-interface.html) and [Overriding Methods](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/overriding-methods-of-a-superclass.html).

Comment: Ok, but this is not what I'm asking for. I don't want to choose methods to implemet. I want IDE to do it for me like Eclipse were doing. For example when I clicked "Add unimplemented methods" inside any `Activity` extented class all of these `onCreate()` `onPause()` `onResume()` were generated.

Comment: Actually, you will be able to choose ALL overridable methods, where eclipse make the choice for you. With eclipse, you were not able to choose exactly what you want to Override. Maybe this way is cleaner one ;)

Comment: the answer below by pbespechnyi is the right one. Alt + Enter

Comment: Yup **'ALT+ENTER'**  should be the right answer **not 'CTRL-O'**

Comment: Would be great to hover the Class and then just click implement methods for me.  Eclipse was so awesome...

Comment: Having the option to choose is not better, actually it is worse. Sometimes superclasses have dozens of methods, and only a couple are abstract, having to choose the right ones between all others is not very user-friendly.

Comment: Eclipse has in this case better solution.

Comment: COMMAND I works on Mac OSX for implementing unimplemented methods. COMMAND O works for importing libraries, I think.

Comment: Now suddenly COMMAND O does not work for importing the class, but 'alt + enter' does.

Comment: Android Studio for Mac doesn't show any new methods. I created a new project, inside onCreate() i simply call a new method `testMethod();` and hit CMD+I, nothing happens, ^I says "no methods to implement have been found"

Answer (score 40):

You can use following shortcuts.

On Windows machine:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> - on class definition;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> - in class body to show list of unimplemented methods.

On Mac:

- <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>Return</kbd> - on class definition (<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>  can be also <kbd>Alt</kbd>);
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> - in class body to show list of unimplemented methods.

There is also useful combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> / <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> - override methods.

Comment: Ok, but this is not what I'm asking for. I don't want to choose methods to implemet. I want IDE to do it for me like Eclipse were doing. For example when I clicked "Add unimplemented methods" inside any `Activity` extented class all of these `onCreate()` `onPause()` `onResume()` were generated.

Comment: Alt + Enter is the right one. Highlight the unimplemented method, hit Alt + Enter, you will get a popup to choose where to create the method.

Comment: Absolutely the right answer. My issue was to just implement the methods and not override them. Simple solution when you implement a class with other.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, this is easy with **Command + N**. This brings up a menu that asks if you want to access the override methods or the interface methods, combining the shortcuts described in the other answers. There is a similar shortcut on Windows, but it's not as convenient.

The source, should they ever change: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-constructors.html

EDIT: or, for interfaces: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/implementing-methods-of-an-interface.html

and supers: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/overriding-methods-of-a-superclass.html

Answer (score 3):

Alt + Enter - on class definition; Ctrl + I - in class body to show list of unimplemented methods. 
Ctrl + O - in class body to show list of **override** methods.

Answer (score 2):

Type
buttonName.setOnClickListener(new ) after that using **Ctrl+Shift+Space** you will get you the right choices.

**Ctrl+Shift+Enter** will make your code syntactically correct

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is 1 year ago, but this might help for future users. 

For windows users, **Alt + Enter > Implement methods ( press Enter ) > ( press Enter)**  works.

This will add the unimplemented methods. 

But you've to move your cursor next to that class or interface.

Answer (score -1):

In linux, Alt+Insert will provide list to implement constructor, setter, getter and implemented method like toString

Comment: This not an answer Please read this to learn how to answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer