# In Android Studio, how get popup of all methods a class can implement (and add them)?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, code-completion

If I've created a class that implements another one (e.g. `class MyFragment extends Fragment`), when I start typing in the class, it is not giving me the code completion for parent methods. How do I get this to show up or get a popup that I can choose them from?

For example, in `MyFragment`, typing `public void onCre` does not show anything. (But after typing the entire method, it compiles fine.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you correctly but can you try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>?

Please also see ["Add unimplemented methods" feature in the Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061187/add-unimplemented-methods-feature-in-the-android-studio).

Answer (score 0):

It should be giving you code completion for those methods. Have you tried doing a "Make Project" to ensure everything's synced with your gradle script?

Alternatively, you can go do "Code > Override..." to bring up a list of available methods to override.