# How to automate adding multiple methods in android studio 1.0?

Tags: java, android, interface, android-studio, libgdx

I am following a tutorial on how to create a flappy bird clone from http://www.kilobolt.com/day-3-understanding-the-libgdx-framework.html

This is where I am at

[image]

I know what's going because GScreen is a concrete class, it has to provide implementations of all the methods in the Screen interface.

To do this, I looked up ["Add unimplemented methods" feature in the Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061187/add-unimplemented-methods-feature-in-the-android-studio)
and used the control o shortcut to get to this dialog.

[image]

However from this dialog, is there a way of selecting multiple methods that you want stubs for? If I double click one, I just get the stub for that method. Is there a way to get multiple stubs at a time, for efficiency sakes?

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple methods using the control (Command on a Mac) key or the shift key, then single click.  The shift key selects a continuous list of methods, the control key allows non-contiguous selections.

Comment: when you're prompted with that prompt? When  I do shift single key, it still just gives me the stub for that one method.

Comment: For example based on the screenshot above, if you click on show(), then hold down the shift key and click on dispose, all the methods will be highlighted, then you can click OK and it will generate the stubs for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can **right click on the class name in java file**. A drop down arrow will come containing an various options like **"GENERATE"**. Click it and select which unimplemented you want to apply it will be automatic generated.