# Shortcut for Overriding methods in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently migrated to Android Studio and I am pretty used to the `Source -> Override/Implement` feature in Eclipse.

[image: Methods in Eclipse]

I was wondering where I could find the same feature on Android Studio. I've tried "Alt-Insert"/Generate-Override methods but I don't find the `OnPause()` method to override in the list. How do I get the methods that I want to override in the list?

These are the only methods that are available to me on my IDE.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061187/add-unimplemented-methods-feature-in-the-android-studio

Comment: @AkshatArora Nope, I've checked that question. None of those mentioned answers work. There are no onPause(), onResume() etc methods showing up in the list. Just the clone():Object and such. Check the image that pops up on my IDE in this case.

Comment: You can only override those methods if the class you're in extends an Android `Fragment`, `Activity`, etc. From the list you posted, it seems like you're in a POJO class.

Comment: @AlexWalterbos, This is the present class "public class MainPage extends ActionBarActivity"

Comment: If you build your project, are there any build errors?

Comment: have the same problem, try to override the function in Fragment class, got nothing but Any class fun.

Answer (score 19):

`Ctrl + O`

should work well in Android Studio.

Comment: I've tried, they just don't show up, refresh your page again to see my list. Thanks.

Comment: Considering only Objects overrides show up, your project may not be set up correctly? [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/1MXzhyw.png) Did you try using brand new project from project creator just for testing?

Comment: I've imported these packages too, I wonder what's wrong.

>import android.content.Intent;
>import android.os.Bundle;
>import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
>import android.view.View;
>import android.widget.Button;

Comment: What happens when you override methods manually? Are plugins for android support in settings turned on? Did you try using new project? If all these fail, I would assume it's Studio bug - try reporting it to google.

Comment: Would it be problem if my class is "MainPage" rather than "Mainpage" ??

Comment: No, name of the class shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Press Alt(Left one)+insert.
It shows all the dialog with heading "Generate"
Choose override methods.

**Shortcut**- Ctrl+O

Answer (score 1):

The method you want to override has to be declared in a class you implement or extend. It might be that your class does not extend `Activity` (for example). And your project might have to be an android project and not a plain java project.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to have the class in your code for Android Studio to offer you the override options pertaining to that class. The image you've posted seems to have only one class.

See how many I got:

[image: See how many I got]