# Firebase FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate recyclerView with firebase contents but i'm catching error.
**This my activity fragment**

```
public class Journal extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference myref;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_journal,container,false);


    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.journal_rv);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/blog");

  // here is the error : "Must implements methods"



    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, BlogViewHolder>(
            JournalEntry.class,
            R.layout.journal_list_item,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            myref
    ) {


// Another one : method does not override from its superclass


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, JournalEntry model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    TextView textView_title;
    TextView textView_decription;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
        textView_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_title);
        textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_event_title);
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        textView_title.setText(title+"");
    }
    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        textView_decription.setText(description);
    }
```

When i implement those methods, I always catch the same error;

can anyone help me?
Ps: I'm using a fragment not an activity.
**UPDATE** i implemented methods like this

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, BlogViewHolder>(
            JournalEntry.class,
            R.layout.journal_list_item,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            myref
    ) {
        @Override
        public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, JournalEntry model) {
            holder.setTitle(model.getEvent_title());
            holder.setDescription(model.getEvent_content());
        }


    };
```

now the error (inside editor) is FirebaseAdaper in firebaseAdapter can not be applied to :

```
JournalEntry.class  (java...consti.last.database.JournalEntry>)


R.layout.journal_list_item  (int)


BlogViewHolder.class  (java...consti.last.Journal.BlogViewHolder>)


myref  (com...firebase.database.DatabaseReference)
```

Comment: Error which is?

Comment: "Must implements methods"

Comment: Please provide the entire error from your logcat.

Comment: [“Add unimplemented methods” feature in the Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061350)

Answer (score 1):

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Remove this line from your code

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to add the following line of code at the end of your `onCreateView()` method:

```
return v;
```

If have also have other `unimplemented methods`, just press in your Android Studio `ALT+Insert` -> select Override Methods -> select the nedded methods.

Comment: Try to add unimplemented methods as explained above.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and removed the 
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); line and it worked. I just don't understand why. Please enlighten me